# how to replace abusive words php

Tags: php

hello all i have a page where i need to replace all the occurrence of some particular words which may be abusive  with a image (same image for all the words)  and i have following function which does the work but it is case sensitive . like it replaces f**k  but not f**k  f**k f**k  f**k  etc.. and i think there is a better way to do this please help .

my function is

```
function filter($text) {
    $icons = array(
            'f**k '    =>  '<img src="smiles/filter.png" class="filter" title="Blured text  "/>',
            'something else'    =>  '<img src="smiles/filter.png" class="filter" title="Blured text  "/>',
            ' something else'   =>  '<img src="smiles/filter.png" class="filter" title="f**k  you ::F"/>'
    );
    return strtr($text, $icons);
}
```

Comment: Just be careful with what you do, or I might find you and buttbuttinate you! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a bigger filter based on RegEx for this

Like this:

```
function filterAbusiveWords( $string ) {

    static $abusiveWords = array( 
        '/f[u]+c?k/i' => 'some icon',
        '/f[\*]+c?k/i' => 'some icon',
        '/f[a]+c?k/i' => 'some icon',
        '/some normal word/i' => 'some icon'
    );

    return preg_replace( array_keys( $abusiveWords ), array_values( $abusiveWords ), $string );
}
```

This would (in theory) replace all occurences of fak, fuck, f*******ck, f**k, faaak, fuk etc.

Comment: but there are hundreds of other word that i need to filter i can not do this way to filter them this is quite long process..

Comment: man your answer is acceptable can you just explain me a little how do i do this with other words . say rahul,sandeep etc.. can you just explain me a little ablut the /[]+?i etc please please...

Comment: Explaining Regular Expressions could take days and a lot more space than this comment field. In short: Everything in [] means "characters of this set", + means "one or more times", * means "0 or more times", ? means "optional" at the end of a statement, i means Case-Insensitive, / are just separators you have to set. For more just read something about Perl Regular Expressions, these are used here